# Proper response to ¿Qué onda?

Tags: saludos, preguntas, coloquialismos

In parts of the Spanish-speaking world, "¿Qué onda?" is used to ask something along the lines of "What's up?". What are the possible responses to this question? Should it be answered with a *bien/mal*, a *nada/mucho*, or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible responses are:

1. Nada.
2. Aquí nada más.
3. Todo bien.
4. Todo perfecto.
5. Echándole ganas.
6. Echándole.
7. Aquí echándole (ganas).
8. Nariz: Pretty casual and informal which means nada.

You can add the "¿Y tú?" to the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 9):

Additional to Alfredo's answer I would like to add some context.

You can answer as you can answer to any greeting. Be aware I am not a Mexican native speaker, although I have friends that come from Mexico.

> Bien, gracias.
>
> No mucho.
>
> Nada
>
> Super bien.
>
> Super mal.
>
> etc...

Now, as a bonus I tease my friends taking the phrase literal. **Onda** is wave. So to just pull their leg you can say:

> ¿Qué onda? - Coseno OR Tangente OR Coseno OR Cosecante OR Magnética [...]

You get it.

As an extra bonus:

The expression **¿Qué onda?** is mostly used in Mexico and orignated from the literature current of the 1960's and 70's but has been used since 1940 more or less. **"La onda"** was referred to in this time to attitudes that where about rebellion against the *status quo*, against the *burgueses* and the rich class. A lot of influence coming from the USSR.

From the book **"Onda y literatura de México"** of **Margo Glantz** :
<sub>Editorial Siglo XXI, 1973</sub>

> "De la jerga de los adolescentes de la clase media se desprende,
>   también, la incorporación, en los textos dela onda, de palabras tabú o
>   tabúes verbales que rayan en lo excesivo de su uso, como excesivo es
>   en el habla cotidiana del pueblo mexicano, en especial, en los
>   jóvenes. Al respecto narra García Saldaña su propia experiencia al
>   transitar por la generación de la onda: "en el principio fueron
>   palabras prohibidas, parecían formar el lenguaje de un terrorista, de
>   un anarquista, de un revolucionario de la nada" (1972: 48). La
>   intención con el empleo de estas palabras tabú era agredir y protestar
>   contra la clase social minoritaria dominante, así como, contra los
>   miembros de otras clases sociales que imitaban los modelos axiológicos
>   y morales de dicha clase social dominante: la burguesía: "ante el
>   pudor de la gente respetable, las palabras eran bombas que explotan
>   frente a su menguada, hipócrita moralidad" (García, 1972: 49). Así
>   demostraban su inconformidad, su rebeldía, su insatisfacción; actitud
>   imitada por aquella generación vanguardista de jóvenes
>   estadounidenses. Sin embargo con esta actitud, no solamente, herían a
>   una clase social sino que también manifestaban su repudio contra el
>   régimen dominante, contra el sistema de gobierno y su estructura
>   social: "para la Institución, la agitación de estos rebeldes no tiene
>   razón de ser. No pertenecen a la adolescencia y a la juventud
>   estudiosas, no se preparan para servir a la patria, no pretenden
>   funcionar dentro de la patria" (García, 1972: 50). De esta manera, el
>   frenetismo así como la insubordinación desgarradora, aprehendidos de
>   la generación beat, se ponen de manifiesto en nuestro país por medio
>   de la generación de la onda. Existió un vínculo entre esos escritores
>   y una forma de conducta, de vestir, de pensar, que dominó durante esa
>   época al mundo y por supuesto a nuestro país en una versión
>   nacionalizada: los hippies o hippitecas, en este caso, quienes
>   adoptaron la actitud de anticonvencionalismo concebida como una
>   respuesta a un sistema social dominante: el capitalismo. La tendencia
>   política por parte de los hippies mexicanos estuvo dirigida hacia el
>   sistema oponente: el socialismo. Tendencia política que alcanza a
>   filtrarse en algunas de las novelas de la onda, como forma también de
>   arraigarse en una forma de pensamiento que se opusiera al consumismo
>   capitalista...."

Answer (score 2):

A common response would be:

> Todo bien, ¿y tú?

Comment: Welcome to Spanish Language & Usage. We highly encourage answers that are complete and that address the question. Sources are desirable but not mandatory. Try improving the answer to prevent other users from flagging it as a Low Quality answer. Have a nice one! :)